# Does the waiting selectors of NSThread accessible?

Tags: ios, macos, nsthread, nsrunloop

I have on many places in my code:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(mySelector:) onThread:myThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I want to know how many selectors are waiting to be performed in **myThread**.

Is it possible?

Comment: I would very much recommend using GCD.

Comment: Agreed. There hasn't been a good reason to use this method in years. Separately, no, you can't do this. Runloops provide very little access to their current state.